# Office 365 / Sharepoint website develoment

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio, master-pages

So our company decides to get a new webpage using SharePoint/office 365. The goal is to make a webpage where any employee with no programming knowledge can simply maintain the contents on the webpage without any hassle.

The problem is, where do i start. I have never worked with SharePoint before, but have experience with visual studio, c#, .net, css, html, javascript etc. I would be grateful if you could give me some links to guides.

I have Googled allot, but did not find much. Maybe different terms are used in SharePoint environment, which could be the reason why i'm not finding anything useful. Or its simply not possible.

Note: not insterested in Azure or developing in a server environment, but instead on a desktop pc.

Comment: To get started with Office 365 development the best site to start is the [developer center](http://dev.office.com/).

Answer (score 0):

i found this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869(v=office.15).aspx

iam not a Sharepoint developer myself, but this seem to be useful.